# How to use diffrent function for different routes from one Controller in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Can I define in ui-router routes which function has to call on particular routes from one controller? Like I have two functions in a controller and both are different. like this -

```
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope, $stateParams){


    $scope.firstFunction = function () {
        $scope.firstVar = 'Hello there';
    };

    $scope.secondFunction = function () {
        $scope.secondVar = 'I am learning Angular JS!';
    };

})
```

I want to use firstFunction or secondFunction for diffrent routes like -

```
adsYogiApp.config([ '$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', 
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {   

        $stateProvider
            .state('app.first', {  // for this route i want to use mainCtrl's firstFunction
                url: "/firstPage", 
                templateUrl : 'views/firstpage.html',
                controller: "mainCtrl"
            })
            .state('app.second', {  // for this route i want to use mainCtrl's secondFunction
                url: "/firstPage", 
                templateUrl : 'views/firstpage.html',
                controller: "mainCtrl"
            });

    }
]);
```

How would I do that ?

Comment: when do you want to call those functions?

Comment: What is the purpose of having 1 controller for 2 states? Does any of the scope variables affect the other?

Comment: I want to get a Data for a diffrent purpose like a magazine published in many cities and many categories (like a business edition, Tech news etc). I want to get data of magazine is city wise and category wise and Single magazine details (like name, a number of copies) so I want to use a magzineController to get three type data. Is that right to get data from one controller or am i thinking in wrong way ?

Comment: dont use same controller in many page , and if you want get different data type , you can use services for this , make your question clearly , post data type you want get and  everyone will help your